# Can't free a typedef struct returned from function

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I'm having an issue which is undoubtedly due to flawed thinking on my part but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've got a struct like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap;
    char name[255];
    signed int  step;       // How many frames to move per cycle. Negative values will cause the animation to reverse. Affects "current" frame only.
    ANNE_SPRITE_CYCLES cycles;
    ANNE_SPRITE_ANIMATIONS anim;
    ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME current;
} ANNE_SPRITE;
```

If I malloc() and then free it immediately after, everything's OK:

```
ANNE_SPRITE *sprite = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_SPRITE));
free(sprite);
printf("Haven't crashed yet, boss!");
```

However, if I build the struct inside a function, like so:

```
ANNE_SPRITE anne_sprite_load(char sprite_name[]){
    ANNE_SPRITE *sprite = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_SPRITE));
    //Snipped: a bunch of code to populate the struct with data
    return *sprite;
}
```

then I can't deallocate the struct in the calling context for love or money:

```
ANNE_SPRITE test = anne_sprite_load("awesome_sprite");
free(test);
```

This yields a compiler error - that I'm `passing 'ANNE_SPRITE' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *'`, in fact - but I'm at a loss for how to finesse this variable into a format free() is prepared to work with.

Comment: `return *sprite;` remove the star.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example returns `ANNE_SPRITE` (i.e. a struct, not a pointer).
You should change the signature to `ANNE_SPRITE* anne_sprite_load(char sprite_name[])` and adjust the `return statement`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ANNE_SPRITE* anne_sprite_load(char sprite_name[]){  // <== Change return type to be a pointer.
    ANNE_SPRITE *sprite = malloc(sizeof(ANNE_SPRITE));
    //Snipped: a bunch of code to populate the struct with data
    return sprite;  // <== Return the pointer.
}


ANNE_SPRITE* pTest = anne_sprite_load("awesome_sprite");  // <== Change to pointer type
free(pTest);  // <== Now free will work
```